# Lightweight, cross-platform input library

Tags: input

I'm trying to write a game with support for Joypads as well as mouse/keyboard. I've tried finding information about that, but it's either outdated or not portable enough.

Does anybody know of any good, lightweight libraries that can abstract Joypad reading? I want to use the 360 controller, but I would like support for more than that.

I'm primarily going to be writing on Windows, but I really don't want to use DirectInput/XInput, in case I ever wish to port my code.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. For C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617359/cross-platform-keyboard-mouse-input-recommendation

Answer (score 11):

Have you ever tryied [OIS](https://github.com/wgois/OIS) ([Object Oriented Input System](https://github.com/wgois/OIS))? An efficient and light weight library.
I am very satisfied with it.

I have never tried with the 360 controller, but it should work fine.

Comment: zlib/libpng License. You are free to use this library in any way you like.

Comment: they still does not mantain a GCC build for windows u.u. I'm still not able to compile it here without visual studio. The main problem is that they have their Window framework/engine, and they ignore feature requests like GCC-build for windows integrating OOIS with other window systems etc.. It appears that now only source release is available (no precompiled binaries)

Answer (score 5):

This maybe an older question and is already answered but..

Someone on tigsource made a lightweight cross-platform gamepad library
that you might find useful.

You can view the post on it [here](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=10675.0).

Answer (score 4):

What about [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_API)?

Maybe it's not what you mean by lightweight (it has the graphic and audio subsystems too), but it's very portable.

Comment: One thing that bugs me about SDL's input system is that remapping your keys may break key events. SDL then says "keyboard layout unknown" and none of your handlers is called...

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is very old and by now you might have gotten what you need, but im answering this just in case someone stumbles on it and needs help as well.

I stumbled upon this library gainput and it seems like it makes alot of sense. You  can try it out, if it helps.

Gainput is a lightweight c++ library, that enables you use the same interface for Joypads, macs, pc, linux as well as mobiles, and it is very easy to integrate to your project.

A link to gainput can be found here (http://gainput.johanneskuhlmann.de/)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -5):

Have you looked at XNA game framework?
There is also

Allero
http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/

GarageGames
http://www.garagegames.com/

Try that out

Comment: XNA is .NET based - that's definitely NOT lightweight, nor cross-platform. Garage-games seems to be a full library, not quite what I'm looking for.

Allegro, on the other hand, looks really interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: Funny that I actually have the answer, although not all parts of it fit, and I get minuses. I believe that is better to have more then to have less and you pick what you need.

Comment: A poor answer is often worse than none.

Comment: Except its not poor, its actually too rich.

Comment: Actually, it's very poor, because it doesn't `fit the question`.

Comment: Well lets just agree to disagree....Andrei said he will be looking into one of the options, that means it might have answered the question, therefore being a fit.