# cross platform keyboard/mouse input recommendation

Tags: c++, c, input, cross-platform

Does anyone have any suggestions for a good cross platform input library?
I'd like to get:

```
* at least keyboard and mouse input
* on at least the big three operating systems
* Small/fast
* C or C++
* permissive licensing gpl2/mit/free/etc.
```

So far I've seen:

```
* OIS (used in Ogre) http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/
* SDL (used everywhere it seems, might be a clue) http://www.libsdl.org/index.php
* Allegro http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/readme.html
```

Has any one used any of these, or know of something else that might be good?

Thanks

Comment: This will often be coupled to the output library, that is, the library that puts things on the screen. Do you intend to show anything on the screen at all?

Comment: I didn't intend any coupling to output. I use the "separation of concerns" model where possible. @jweyrich gave some good suggestions but it looks like both of them do much more than just input.

Comment: I would suggest OOIS (OpenInputSystem) that library supports multiple mices in theory. In practice I had compability and compile problems (it uses DX on windows and won't compile with GCC on windows), also it caused problems when used with other windowing systems (SFML) and asking for help on both sites ended in "it is fault of the other library". So i'm still waiting for multiple keyboards and mice support! u.u

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Qt framework for this.

It's very complete, well supported, has a lot of features, and has better licensing now. It was possible to use it with the Ogre3d library so it worked out well for me. I also found that it's being used by the City of Heroes MMO for their user interface.

Answer (score 4):

I've used SDL for long time, <s>but it still doesn't support multiple windows,</s> and [version 2.0 officially supports multiple windows](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Introduction).

So, beyond those you cited, I add these 2:

- [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/)
- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: Both of those look like excellent candidates :)

Comment: SDL Supports multiple windows now.

Comment: @Jordan indeed! I've updated my answer to reflect this :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

SDL it is quite popular in game development (at least small games)